# Storing thousands of Image files in mongo database using Grid fs , is it a good idea?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, gridfs

The feature that I wanted to implement is store multiple images to mongo using the mongo grid fs where the files are from remote server which I do have the urls like for example to download or get the file. Now I want to store that images to my mongo db there are hundres of that urls.

Question is do I need to download all those images from the remote server before I can store it on my mongo db? does it make it redundant ? that I need to download all the files on the file system and then store it on my mongo database ? Is there a better implementation compared to this ? is it a good idea to implement this way ?

Sample:

```
https://datacontent.test.com/2000017/2098449/0x0/122223sss34ccca02cf3f4b0aa4b2ebb88218dbedc1d01.jpg
```

On working with mysql database, it is a bad idea to store images as BLOB in the database, as it makes the database quite large which is harmful for normal usage of the database. Then, it is better to save image files on disk and save link to them within the database.

However, I think this is different for MongoDB with the use of mongo Grid FS.

Comment: Usually, you have to store 'path to image's in database. DB is mainly for querying not just for storing... What can you do with raw images in a database?

Comment: But the images are from remote server Sir @GyuHyeonChoi , Do I need to download those images first right ?

Comment: All images are in remote servers in some sense? I think you can store remote paths to those images. Aren't they accessible...?

Comment: they are accessible

Comment: If I just store the path using grid fs wont make sense

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi , the reason why the files are need to be download is that so we can have our own copy in the case the server is removed.

Comment: I came back after reading some articles. I still think it is better to store paths, unless you are parcticing `GridFS` [https://www.reddit.com/r/mongodb/comments/6t4wfn/is_storing_images_in_a_mongodb_database_really/].

Comment: the problem storing path is that you dont have a copy of the files so if the server serving it lost or down you no longer have access to those images.

Comment: But let us just say that I am practicing GRID FS .

Comment: In that case, storing in a MongoDB seems better... I just still think managing raw files is easier than managing database.

Comment: Oh, I got it. sorry... @_@ You cannot access to your MongoDB from that sever?

Comment: So the choice i got is to download the files from the remote server then store in on my mongo db using grid fs

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi , can i ask a question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200041/discussion-between-mr-mark-tawin-and-gyuhyeon-choi).